Federated SAML 2.0 SSO login with Spring Authorization Server
The requirement is to implement Single Sign On(SSO) with SAML using Spring Authorization Server, based on Service Provider(SP) initiated flow.
Does Spring Authorization Server support SSO with SAML? If not, what is the way to achieve SSO using SAML with Spring Authorization Server?
Image depicting the flow:
Spring Authorization Server(SAS) login page --> Redirect to SAML Identity Provider login page --> User logs in --> Return SAML Assertion to SAS --> SAS generates JWT tokens
This issue is about the same question that I have - Federated authentication using external identity providers. However, I'm looking for a guide and code samples to implement the SSO solution with SAML.
Spring Authorization Server Feature List seems to contain no information about SAML SSO support.
This question does not contain much information about SAML SSO - Federate authorization requests with Spring Authorization Server.
